# Is Jquery.load() function treated as ajax in Django view

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-views

I am loading the content via `jquery.load(url)`

I want to know is it considered as ajax call because i have loop in djnago

`if request.is_ajax()`

Now this loop is not executed if i use load but executed if i use $.ajax or post or get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is_ajax() does is checks for the existence of the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header in the request.  By default Jquery does add that for all .ajax calls which would include .load.  The only time that it does not add it is if the request is considered cross-domain.

However, even in that case you could still if you really wanted to override it and set headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] = "XMLHttpRequest";